# Quick yet extensive GUI designer/builder

Tags: user-interface, ide, designer

Every time I create a GUI, I use visual studios CLR/C++ winforms design tool. I really like it, it has a lot of features, it's fairly easy to use, and I love that it generates all the code. But there are a few things I don't like about it. Namely: it can be very time demanding to make programs with a lot of controls.

I'm starting to sense that not many people use CLR winforms to make GUI's. I'm not as informed on the "mainstream" programming practices, since I'm teaching myself how to program. I've messed around with Qt and VBA for Excel, but I don't want to spend too much time on them just to find out there is something better for my purposes.

Which GUI designer/builder software would you recommend considering the following? I'm interested in a tool to quickly make quality GUI's. Programming language and learning curve are not important. I'd much rather invest time learning how to use complex software than spend time tediously piecing together GUI's. This tool should be very exhaustive, the more functionality the better.

(TL;DR) In short I'm looking for a very productive GUI designer/builder sporting a large number of efficiency boosting tools, regardless of language.

Although programming language isn't an important factor directly, I do enjoy object oriented languages as I feel they can be very efficient on time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you look again at QtCreator, especially in combination with Qt's [QML language](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlapplications.html). In short, you can think of QML as a hybrid "language" which resembles CSS syntax, mixed with Javascript. You can have a look at the [TableView example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html#details) and find out by yourself how simple, yet powerful it is :)

I personally find it awesome because designers can sketch an entire application user interface in few hours (good for rapid prototyping), which is working with mock models, while developers can focus in the core application (because, i forgot to tell you, [QML can talk to the "old" Qt framework, and viceversa](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html) ).

Comment: When I played around with Qt I was on some kind of free trial (which expired before I could get my hands dirty). Does it cost money if the programs I'm developing are strictly for personal use?